# RAID 1 and RAID 10 together?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

I have a server with 10 drives, looking to set up RAID 1 on the first 2 drives (for the OS) and RAID 10 on the remaining 8 (for database).

When I'm rolling through this set up in Dell Lifecycle Controller, I finish the first RAID fine. When I set up the second RAID on the remaining 8 drives, I get a warning:

> If any modifications are applied, the virtual disk configuration is lost on all the virtual disks in the system.

If I go through with this, it indeed does wipe out my RAID 1 setup I made earlier.

What am I missing? How would one set up accomplish this set up?

Controller: PERC H730 Integrated RAID Controller, 1GB Cache

Comment: Did you create a second virtual disk for the second RAID set? Are you using a software or hardware RAID controller?

Comment: @JarrodL.J.Gibson Hardware. I believe a 2nd virtual disk creation is part of the steps? Step 4 asks to create a "Virtual Disk Name" so it was my assumption it was creating a new one.

Comment: What controller are you using? S100, S300, H300, H700?

Comment: @JarrodL.J.Gibson Added into OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H730 can definitely do multiple raid. It sounds like you might have selected the two disks that are already assigned to your RAID1 while creating your RAID10.

This article could help guide you through the setup process: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/dell-server-perc-h700-create-raid/

Also, try making sure your BIOS and RAID controller firmware are fully updated.

Comment: Does that mean Dell Lifecycle Controller cannot accomplish this?

Comment: I'm sure you could, by I would typically bypass this as I'm more familiar with the old fashioned way.

Comment: Lifecycle Controller has no issues with mix raid types.